# Centos 7.9 python3 cant find modules installed via yum

Tags: python, yum, pip

My stub python3 program cannot find the "pytz" module:

```
[me@mybox]$ uname -a
Linux portal2 3.10.0-1160.53.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 14 13:59:45 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[me@mybox]$ cat /etc/redhat-release 
CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
[me@mybox]$ 
[me@mybox]$ cat t2b.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import datetime
import time
import pytz

from datetime import datetime, timezone, tzinfo


[me@mybox]$  ./t2b.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./t2b.py", line 6, in <module>
    import pytz
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytz'
[me@mybox]$
```

"yum" on my Centos 7 box provides the 'pytz' module, so I installed it (many lines deleted):

```
[root@mybox ~]# yum install pytz
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Determining fastest mirrors
.     .     .     .     .
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package pytz.noarch 0:2016.10-2.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
.     .     .     .     .
Dependencies Resolved
.     .     .     .     .
Installing:
 pytz           noarch           2016.10-2.el7             base            46 k
.     .     .     .     .
Installed:
  pytz.noarch 0:2016.10-2.el7

Complete!
[root@mybox ~]#
```

But after this, my stub program failed in the identical manner! As far as it was concerned, there was still " No module named 'pytz' ", even after a reboot and logging back in.

It was not until after I installed the 'pytz' module via 'pip3' that t2b.py could find it.

```
[root@portal2 ~]# pip3 install pytz
WARNING: Running pip install with root privileges is generally not a good idea. Try `pip3 install --user` instead.
Collecting pytz
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d3/e3/d9f046b5d1c94a3aeab15f1f867aa414f8ee9d196fae6865f1d6a0ee1a0b/pytz-2021.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (503kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 512kB 2.0MB/s 
Installing collected packages: pytz
Successfully installed pytz-2021.3
[root@portal2 ~]#

[kurt@mybox ]$ ./t2b.py 
[kurt@mybox ]$
```

As far as possible I'd like to uniformly maintain installed software via "yum". My question is why will this not work for this python3 module, and/or what additional steps do I have to take for the process to work properly?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing makes the obvious answers pop up in front of you like going through the work of asking the question. It appears that I installed 'pytz' for python2:

```
[root@mybox ~]# yum list all | grep pytz
pytz.noarch                                2016.10-2.el7          @base         
python36-pytz.noarch                       2017.2-3.el7           epel          
rh-python38-python-pytz.noarch             2019.3-4.el7           centos-sclo-rh
[root@pmybox ~]# python3 -V
Python 3.6.8
[root@mybox ~]#
```

It is unsurprising that my little python3 program could not find that. Most likely I should have installed 'python36-pytz', and my program would have found it.

Comment: "yum info <pkgname up to the '.'>" gives details about each package, even if it's not locally installed.